# Read external stage file from snowflake java UDF

Tags: snowflake-schema, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created a java UDF to read word documents from my external stage. I used the imports clause where I imported all my external stage files and used them in my java UDF. It looks not ok for me.
Are there any other ways to read the files from the stage dynamically?

Comment: Can you share the relevant portions of the Java UDF and clarify what "not ok" means? Sample data (if relevant) or file names, relevant sections of Java in the UDF, and intended results will help resolve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic reading of files from stages using Java UDFs as shown at the Snowflake Summit is not yet supported. You can access any files from the `IMPORTS` list as part of execution, however, which should generally be used for reading configuration files, models, etc. Using a slight adaptation of [the sample in the documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/java/udf-java-cookbook.html#sample-code-for-reading-a-file), you can do something like this:

```sql
create function ReadImportedFile(file_name varchar)
returns varchar
language java
imports = ('@my_stage/my_path/my_config_file_1.txt',
           '@my_stage/my_path/my_config_file_2.txt')
handler = 'my_package.TestReadRelativeFile.readFile' as $$
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

class TestReadRelativeFile {
    // Reads the text file with the specified name, which must be part of the
    // IMPORTS list.
    public String readFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder contentBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String importDirectory = System.getProperty("com.snowflake.import_directory");
        String fPath = importDirectory + fileName;
        Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fPath), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        stream.forEach(s -> contentBuilder.append(s).append("\n"));
        return contentBuilder.toString();
    }
}
$$;

-- This reads the contents of my_config_file_1.txt, which was named in the
-- IMPORTS list in the function declaration.
select ReadImportedFile('my_config_file_1.txt');
```

If you're having issues reading files using this pattern, it would be good to clarify what is going wrong as part of your question.

Comment: Thanks Elliott Brossard. Is that possible to read the files directly from the S3 using Java AWS SDK and then use them in snowflake? As per snowflake documentation, the files imports clause is temporally loaded into com.snowflake.import.directory.Not sure how the snowflake treat this case ?

Comment: You cannot use the Java AWS SDK from a Java UDF because Java UDFs do not have network access. If you copy the files to S3 and [create a stage from them](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-stage.html), then you can list the files in the `IMPORTS` clause and use the pattern from my answer to access them.

Comment: Thanks Elliott Brossard, this helps lot.

Comment: Elliott Brossard, I will share my use case, I have plenty of the documents in S3, I need to extract few contents from that document and store them in snowflake tables. I have written the Java UDF function which takes a filename as a parameter. It's possible to load the table by adding the file entry in the imports clause. considering my file count it is not possible to add all file entries into the imports clause. so looking for the dynamic option. Do you suggest any other way to archive this?

Comment: Dynamic reading of files will be supported at some point in the future, which will let you read whichever files you need in a UDF as part of execution. It is not yet supported, however.

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake supports using standard SQL to query data files located in an internal (i.e. Snowflake) stage or named external (Amazon S3, Google Cloud Storage, or Microsoft Azure) stage. This can be useful for inspecting/viewing the contents of the staged files, particularly before loading or after unloading data

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-stage.html